# Integration of Cordova App in a Zend Framework website

Tags: php, angularjs, cordova, zend-framework, ionic-framework

I've done a small Cordova app, to run on an Android device, and I also want it to work in browser.

Now, I have this app, which is working, but I wanted to use it on my Zend framework website. I don't have a single idea about how to do it, and i'm searching for others devs who did this on their site.

Thank you in advance for your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i found how to do it, I needed to remove html, head, and script tags, to add them through

$this->headScript()->appendFile, and I put all my files in the public folder.